# How to deploy or expose Swagger documentation for a service secured over https

Tags: rest, https, swagger

I am having an application which is secured over a 2-way ssl. We are using Swagger to generate documentation for the service automatically. Now the problem is that as part of the deployment the url for the documentation can also be accessed via https since it is part of the application.

This creates a problem since only few people and applications will have the certificates necessary to access the url while a lot more people will need access to the documentation.

What is the right way to expose Swagger documentation in this situation?

I am not sure if this is a question asking for opinions and hence against Stackoverflow standards. If so, I can move it to the appropriate forum.

Comment: A lot of this is going to depend on what framework your app is written in and what web server you're using, can you add detail on that?

Comment: Sorry for missing out on the details. I was lost thinking at a conceptual level :)

So - I am using Spring Rest to develop the rest service and deploying it on JBoss AS. For generating swagger documentation - am using the kongchen impl. And the build is done via Maven. Please let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: I would suggest you use simple http for access and then add a layer of authorization as to which users can view which documentation. Ref: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#515-authorization-object

Comment: Thanks Sampada. I ended up doing the same. :)